# How to get errorInfo in getDerivedStateFromError

Tags: reactjs

Based on React's [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html) an error boundary component should be a class component and it should have these two methods:

```
  static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
    // Update state so the next render will show the fallback UI.
    return { hasError: true };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo) {
    // You can also log the error to an error reporting service
    logErrorToMyService(error, errorInfo);
  }
```

The point is, we want to see the call stack in the development environment in the UI too.

But React says that we should not set state in `componentDidCatch` as it's going to be deprecated.

How can get `errorInfo` in `getDerivedStateFromError`?